# Can I create a while loop in python where the condition is to run while a different function is running?

Tags: python, while-loop, psutil

It's a bit difficult to word.

Essentially I have a small program running in python that parses an XML file and I measure the time it takes for that to run. I am also outputting the resulting tree. I would also like to measure my CPU usage throughout the running of this function, which I want to output to a different text file.

I am using psutil to measure the cpu usage but I do not know how to make a condition for the output only to occur while my parsing/time-recording function is running. Does anyone know how?

Comment: When using multithreading there are synchronization primitives like e. g. "Lock" objects to pause execution of thread.

Comment: Python executes its code sequential one instruction after another. While running a function it runs the function not executing any subsequent code until the function returns. Without a work-around (separate processes, multi-threading, ...) you can't run both at the same time, the function and the while loop asking if a function is running. So the simplest general valid answer is: **you can't**,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.